# Вывод данных из БД в разные TabItem WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, tabcontrol

У меня имеется несколько элементов `TabItem` и, допустим, некоторая информация в базе данных. Например, я хочу вывести на одну вкладку какую-то теорию, а на вторую - задания к этой теории. Есть два вопроса на эту тему:

1. Стоит ли в данном случае прибегать к работе с базой данных, чтобы динамически заполнять `TabItem`, или все же лучше заполнить его статически?
2. Если все же имеет место быть динамическому заполнению, то как его лучше было бы реализовать?

Comment: Можно по-всякому, а как вам надо? Посмотрите, поизучайте, что такое MVVM в WPF и как работают привязки данных `Binding`. При разработке под WPF, так как задумано его разработчиками, многие задачи становятся простыми и не вызывают подобных вопросов.

Comment: [Ну и вот это можно почитать](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/ru/15/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-textblock-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/) про форматирование текста в `TextBlock`.

Comment: @aepot У меня была мысль насчет привязок, но я не знаю, можно ли с их помощью обращаться к конкретным записям таблиц, а не выводить все содержимое разом  (допустим, если у меня есть множество заголовков к теоретическому материалу, а я хочу вывести один конкретный).

Comment: Привязка делается к свойству определенного типа. Что положите в это свойство, то и будет отображаться. Например вы можете загрузить все заголовки из базы в коллекцию, а при обращению к свойству, оно будет возвращать тот заголовок, который нужен согласно выбранному вопросу. `public QuestionTitle { get => Titles[SelectedQuestionId]; }` Для того чтобы интерфейс обновился, вам нужно будет всего-лишь вызвать событие `PropertyChanged`, передав в аргументы имя свойства `nameof(QuestionTitle)`. [Примеров куча](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%5Bwpf%5D+%5Bmvvm%5D+isaccepted%3Ayes).

Comment: @aepot А можно попросить Вас сделать подобный пример для наглядности? Я думаю, он не только мне пригодится. Если Вам не сложно, конечно